# Export Xcode MVC project to .framework file

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

How can I export an MVC project from Xcode to a single file .framework.
The project is very big, around 1 GB and the company want to embed this big project into a single library.
Can you help me to do this ?
Because on internet I can’t find any solution for a big project, just for a single file.
Thanks !

Edit: Here is a screenshot with my structure:
[image: Structure MVC]

Comment: Without any code or details it's hard to answer. But a few things. First I *hope very VERY much* that the "MVC" project isn't a single file. Next, you aren't forced to a single file for a Framework project. Just import the files you need! (And yes, you *can* import views, virtually anything.) Finally, at the *very* least, are you working with iOS or macOS? Both source and new targets. Please, more details.

Comment: My project is an Augmented Reality project. Was exported from Unity to iOS, after I embed that iOS project into Swift 4 and now they want it to be a .framework library. So I really don't know how to embed that big project into a .framework file.
I will attach to the main thread a screenshot with my structure and maybe will help you to guide me.
Thank you so much for your time !

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu Did you found any solution on it. 
I am also facing the same issue. Could you please help me with it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add new target CocoaTouch Static Library (File -> New -> Target -> Cocoa Touch Static Library)
2. Add the project files to the target
   Select a file which you want to add in project navigator pane then in File Inspector (View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector) in the section "targets" check a checkmark.
3. Build

Comment: Thanks @Adobels for your answer but need to be ".framework" not ".a" extension. This is the requirement. Also I've tried your guide but is not working because I have few hundred files and all files with ".h" don't have the target checkbox so I can't include them into the library and the library will have missing files so will crash. I'm still looking to find a solution to integrate all the project into a .framework library. If anyone know a solution please don't avoid to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu Do this for .framework  (File -> New -> Target -> Framework)